# Getting Top Student and calculating average score

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

We are given the Java class Student, class Randomizer, and class Classroom. 
We were told to fill in the method for getTopStudent and getAverageScore.

Below I have included the classes for Student, Classroom, and ClassroomTester.

The problem: when I run it, the compiler errors.

And I don't get why it's wrong...I did not forget a semicolon and I am not sure what they meant by "illegal start of expression"

```js
public class Student
{
    private static final int NUM_EXAMS = 4;
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int gradeLevel;
    private double gpa;
    
    private int[] exams;
    private int numExamsTaken;

  
    public Student(String fName, String lName, int grade)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        gradeLevel = grade;
        exams = new int[NUM_EXAMS];
        numExamsTaken = 0;
    }
    
    public double getAverageScore()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < exams.length;i++)
        {
            sum+=exams[i];
        }
        return (double)sum/numExamsTaken;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    
    public void addExamScore(int score)
    {
        exams[numExamsTaken] = score;
        numExamsTaken++;
    }
    
    // This is a setter method to set the GPA for the Student.
    public void setGPA(double theGPA)
    {
        gpa = theGPA;
    }
    
 
    public String toString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " is in grade: " + gradeLevel;
    }
}
```

```js
public class Classroom
{
    Student[] students;
    int numStudentsAdded;
    
    public Classroom(int numStudents)
    {
        students = new Student[numStudents];
    
    public Student getTopStudent()
    {
        double max = students[0].getAverageScore();
        String topstudent = students[0].getName();
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) 
        {
           if (students[i].getAverageScore() > max) 
           {
               max = students[i].getAverageScore();
               topstudent = students[i];
           }
        }  
        return topstudent;
    }
    public void addStudent(Student s)
    {
        students[numStudentsAdded] = s;
        numStudentsAdded++;
    }
    
    public void printStudents()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numStudentsAdded; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
public class ClassroomTester extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        Classroom c = new Classroom(2);
        
        Student ada = new Student("Ada", "Lovelace", 12);
        ada.addExamScore(44);
        ada.addExamScore(65);
        ada.addExamScore(77);

        Student alan = new Student("Alan", "Turing", 11);
        alan.addExamScore(38);
        alan.addExamScore(24);
        alan.addExamScore(31);

        // add students to classroom
        c.addStudent(ada);
        c.addStudent(alan);
        c.printStudents();
        
        Student topStudent = c.getTopStudent();
        System.out.println(topStudent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of Classroom to

```
        public Classroom(int numStudents)
{
    students = new Student[numStudents];

}
```

You are missing the closing brace } on the constructor of Classroom.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a closing `{`

```
public Classroom(int numStudents)
    {
        students = new Student[numStudents];
```